# TypeScript not detecting incorrect type in React

Tags: typescript

can you please help me to understand how TypeScript works, I am trying to learn it but can't figure out this behaviour.

1 example: is not detecting type errors, please look the commented message on the code

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type Recipe = {
  title: number; ///// TITLE IS A STRING NOT A NUMBER ////
  image: string;
};

export default function Categories() {
  const { category } = useParams();
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState<Recipe[]>([]); //////USING TYPE RECIPE/////

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get<Recipe[]>(  /////USING SAME TYPE RECIPE /////
          `https://mealtime-dkgl.onrender.com/api/recipes/${category}`
        );
        const extractedRecipes = response.data.map((recipe) => ({
          title: recipe.title,
          image: recipe.image,
        }));

        setRecipes(extractedRecipes); /////// NO ERRORS DETECTED ///////
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching recipes", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [category]);

  console.log(recipes);

  return <main></main>;
}
```

2 example: It seems to work as I expected

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type Recipe = {
  title: string;
  image: string;
};

type RecipeResponse = {
  title: number; ////// ERROR IS HERE /////////
  image: string;
};
export default function categories() {
  const { category } = useParams();
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState<Recipe[]>([]); /////// USING TYPE RECIPE //////

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get<RecipeResponse[]>( //// USING TYPE RECIPE RESPONSE /////
        `https://mealtime-dkgl.onrender.com/api/recipes/${category}`
      );
      const extractedRecipes = response.data.map((recipe) => ({
        title: recipe.title,
        image: recipe.image,
      }));

      setRecipes(extractedRecipes); /////ERROR DETECTED/////
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [category]);

  return <main></main>;
}
```

I hope my snippets are clear enough.. but in a nutshell I can't re-use "type Recipe" multiple times in my code, otherwise no error are detected.

Comment: Well it seems that your data is divergent. You're already telling that the response you receive from axios do not overlap with `Recipe` type. If title come as a number from axios you need to explicitly convert `title` into a string so that it will be compliant with `Recipe`.if you're telling ts that your response is already a `Recipe` compliant type (like the first example) you're ts will assume that `title` is indeed a string and will not throw. Remember, ts doesn't know this values at execution type and will therefore take your word that the response is from a specific type although it isn't

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you explicitly tell TypeScript that something is a number, it will assume that is accurate, there is no (built-in) run-time checking of the data coming back from your API, TS is a compile time safety net, extra run-time safety is up to you.

Comment: In my first example I am saying explicitly that title is a number, it should be here that typescript stop me to say " hey this is not correct" , or I am thinking wrong?

Comment: In your first example you said that `title` is a number. Typescript said: "Ok, from now on if `title` receives anything other than a number, I'll accuse an error". After this you write `title: recipe.title`. Typescript then says: "I know that `recipe.title` is, a number, since `recipe` has type `Recipe`, so everything is OK". If you wanted Typescript to know that `recipe.title` is a string you should have used a type that specified it as a string, which is what you did in the second example.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the explanations, 

About "best practices"   which one of the two example is the "correct path to follow"?  if you were in me which approach of the two you would keep on your project?. Thank you again for all the answers and support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript only knows as much as what it's told. If you specify a type and TS finds no conflicts, it won't complain (even if you specified the wrong type).

### First Example

Here's what happened in the first example (with some simplifications):

1. You wrongly specified the type `Recipe` (saying that `title` is a `number`):

```js
type Recipe = {
  title: number;
  image: string;
};
```

2. You made an API call and said that the elements would all be of type `Recipe`. You know that the API will return `{ title: string, image: string }`, but TS has no idea. It just trusts you, after all there is no reason to doubt you (it can't possibly know beforehand what the API returns without making the request).

```js
const response = await axios.get<Recipe[]>(...
```

3. You then process the response.

```js
const extractedRecipes = response.map((recipe) => ({
    title: recipe.title,
    image: recipe.image,
}));
```

Here TS can make some inferences based on the information it has. You said that `response` is an array of `Recipe`, so it knows that in the `map` callback, `recipe.title` is a `number` and `recipe.image` is a `string`.

The end result is that `extractedRecipes` is an array where elements have the type `{ title: number, image: string }`, which is compatible with `Recipe`.

4. Finally, you set the state, and there's no error.

```js
setRecipes(extractedRecipes);
```

The call `useState<Recipe[]>([])` defined the type as `Recipe[]` and you are passing a `Recipe[]` to `setRecipes`, so TypeScript sees nothing wrong. Everything makes perfect sense.

### Second example

In the second example the differences are:

1. `Recipe` is defined correctly and you introduced a new type `RecipeResponse` for the API response.

```js
type Recipe = {
  title: string;
  image: string;
};

type RecipeResponse = {
  title: number;
  image: string;
};
```

2. The response is now an array of `RecipeResponse`

```js
const response = await axios.get<RecipeResponse[]>(...
```

3. Processing step now results in an array of elements with the type `{ title: number, image: string }`, which is compatible with `RecipeResponse`.

```js
const extractedRecipes = response.map((recipe) => ({
    title: recipe.title,
    image: recipe.image,
}));
```

4. The initial `useState<Recipe[]>([])` defines the type as `Recipe[]`. You use `setState` passing `RecipeResponse[]` instead of `Recipe[]`. TS catches it and there's an error.

```js
setRecipes(extractedRecipes);
```

### Conclusion

TypeScript is just a sanity check. It is just there to make sure that your code stays coherent within the restrictions that were defined.

In both examples it did the same thing: it just checked if things were making sense and the restrictions were being enforced.

In the first example you modeled the data in a way that didn't represent reality. Did TS fail by not accusing an error? Not really. Its job is to take restrictions, annotations, contracts or whatever and guarantee that they are being followed. Nothing was violated? TS stays silent.

In the second example you defined a set of restrictions and later on an operation violated them. TS shouted.

#### On best practices

About your question on "best practices" I would say that it isn't worth it to think about that. Just model things as close to reality as possible.

The resources returned by the API have the exact same type as the objects I plan to store? Sure, use the same type for both.

The resources returned by the API have some properties that can be null and I don't wanna store nulls? Whatever, let's create a new type for the API response that has nullable properties.

TypeScript provides a ton of [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html), [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) and [ways to combine them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) so that you can make restrictions that closely represent what you expect to encounter.